# Using recursion in math.pow to calculate power in java

Tags: java, math, recursion

X^n =  ( X^n / 2 )^2 if n > 0 and n is even

X^n =  X * ( X^n / 2 )^2 if n > 0 and n is odd

Can someone give me the java code for these two formulas? I tried to do with it but my answer is always infinity.

Here is my code

Code:

```
import java.lang.*;
public class power4
{
  double ans;
  public double setpower(double x, double n) {
    if (n == 0)
      return 1;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
      return Math.pow(setpower(x, n/2),2);
    else
      return x * (Math.pow(setpower(x, n/2),2));
  }
}
```

Driver Class:

```
 public class powerTester
 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     power4 test4 = new power4();

     System.out.print("2^0 -- ");
     System.out.print(test4.setpower(2,0)+"    ");

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print("2^1 -- ");
     System.out.print(test4.setpower(2,1)+"    ");

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print("2^2 -- ");
     System.out.print(test4.setpower(2,2)+"    ");

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print("2^3 -- ");
     System.out.print(test4.setpower(2,3)+"    ");

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print("2^4 -- ");
     System.out.print(test4.setpower(2,4)+"   ");

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print("2^5 -- ");
     System.out.print(test4.setpower(2,5)+"   ");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\Users\Nisarg\Desktop
> run powerTester
2^0 -- 1.0    
2^1 -- Infinity    
2^2 -- Infinity    
2^3 -- Infinity    
2^4 -- Infinity   
2^5 -- Infinity   >
```

Comment: I think you want `n` to be an integer.  But if you're using `Math.pow` anyway, why not use it to get your answer?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's not really a "give me the code" question, it's a "here's what I've tried, what did I do wrong" question.  It's complete, verifiable, and specifies the expected and actual output.  So I don't think it deserves the close vote.  However, I too have broken the rules by providing the answer in a comment.

Comment: @DavidWallace: fair enough. Close vote / down vote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula

```
X^n = X * ( X^ (n / 2))^2
```

relies on `n / 2` being an integer division of an odd number.  In other words, it doesn't require `n ÷ 2` but actually `(n - 1) ÷ 2`.  By having `n` as a `double` not an integer, you are making the division work exactly, rather than as an integer division.

The result of this is that this recursion only terminates when `n / 2` reaches the limits of floating point precision, by which time you've multiplied in `X` over and over again.  The result is therefore a very large number; too large to be stored in a `double`.

To fix this, change the first line of your `setpower` method to

```
public double setpower(double x, int n)
```

to force the integer division.